# Как можно защитить сайт, написанный на PHP?

Tags: php

Какие виды защиты есть для сайта, написанного на PHP, чтобы избежать в дальнейшем атак от хакеров? Я новичок в программировании PHP, пожалуйста, делитесь советами, пишу сайт, сразу думаю теперь о защите.

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос достаточно широкий. На что нужно обратить внимание.

- Всегда проверять параметры (особенно `$_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE`), например, проверять, что города - это города, а номера - номера.
- Использовать надежную аутентификацию (`PEAR::Auth` и т.п.).
- Убедиться, что настройки сервера не позволяют читать чувствительные данные сессий извне.
- Всегда фильтровать внешние данные (`htmlspecialchars` и т.п.) при отображении.
- Принять меры по защите от SQL-инъекций (`mysql_real_escape_string` и т.п.).

Answer (score 1):

[Ответ кроется в поиске!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search/?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0&t=question)

Answer (score 0):

Еще одна штуковина для предупреждения взлома, сигналка для сайта: http://jkeks.ru/jAntivirus